# Remove row-specific items from list

Tags: r, data.table

I would like to create the last column ('desired_result') from the 3 prior columns ('group', 'animal', and 'full'). Below is code for a reproducible example.

```
library(data.table)
data = data.table(group = c(1,1,1,2,2,2), animal = c('cat', 'dog', 'pig', 'giraffe', 'lion', 'tiger'), desired_result = c('dog, pig', 'cat, pig', 'cat, dog', 'lion, tiger', 'giraffe, tiger', 'giraffe, lion'))
data[, full := list(list(animal)), by = 'group']
data = data[, .(group, animal, full, desired_result)]

data
    group  animal               full   desired_result
1:     1     cat          cat,dog,pig     dog, pig
2:     1     dog          cat,dog,pig     cat, pig
3:     1     pig          cat,dog,pig     cat, dog
4:     2 giraffe   giraffe,lion,tiger    lion, tiger
5:     2    lion   giraffe,lion,tiger    giraffe, tiger
6:     2   tiger   giraffe,lion,tiger    giraffe, lion
```

Basically, I would like to modify 'full' so it does not include the corresponding 'animal'. I have tried various lapply commands using both list and character versions of these columns but have not been able to solve this problem.

Answer (score 3):

Here's a possible approach

```
data[, desired_result := {
        temp <- unique(unlist(full)) 
        toString(temp[-match(animal, temp)])
        }, by = .(group, animal)]
data
#    group  animal               full desired_result
# 1:     1     cat        cat,dog,pig       dog, pig
# 2:     1     dog        cat,dog,pig       cat, pig
# 3:     1     pig        cat,dog,pig       cat, dog
# 4:     2 giraffe giraffe,lion,tiger    lion, tiger
# 5:     2    lion giraffe,lion,tiger giraffe, tiger
# 6:     2   tiger giraffe,lion,tiger  giraffe, lion
```

Answer (score 3):

Another option:

```
data[, desired := .(Map(setdiff, list(animal), as.list(animal))), by = group]

#or if starting from full
data[, desired := .(Map(setdiff, full, animal))]
```

(recycling magic makes the first version work)

Comment: Same idea in `dplyr`: `library(dplyr); data %>% mutate(desired = Map(setdiff, full, animal))`

Comment: This will give a list back instead of character vector (as per OPs desired output).

Comment: I read OP as they don't care if they get a list or a string and conversion is trivial

Comment: I should've mentioned I am not picky between list or string. As eddi said, conversion is not hard.

Comment: Maybe, I just looked at their provided desired out put which was explicitly a character vector. But it seems you are right

Answer (score 1):

I found a way as well!

By turning 'animal' into a list, I can use mapply.

```
data$animal = strsplit(data$animal, ' ')
data$check = mapply(function(x, y) {list(x[x != y]) }, data$full, data$animal)

data
group  animal               full desired_result         check
1:     1     cat        cat,dog,pig       dog, pig       dog,pig
2:     1     dog        cat,dog,pig       cat, pig       cat,pig
3:     1     pig        cat,dog,pig       cat, dog       cat,dog
4:     2 giraffe giraffe,lion,tiger    lion, tiger    lion,tiger
5:     2    lion giraffe,lion,tiger giraffe, tiger giraffe,tiger
6:     2   tiger giraffe,lion,tiger  giraffe, lion  giraffe,lion
```

Comment: Your approach will return a list back instead of a character vector (as per your desired output)

Comment: Ah ok good point, that would have to be converted and cleaned if necessary.